# How To Securely Store Data In MySQL Using AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: mysql, aes

We are storing sensitive data in MySQL, and I want to use AES_ENCRYPT(data, 'my-secret-key-here') and then AES_DECRYPT which works great. My biggest question is how do I secure the key? Previously I just wast storing the key in a web PHP file, so something like:

```
define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", 'my-secret-key-here');
```

This really doesn't work though, as our MySQL server and web server are the same physical machine, so if somebody gains access to the server, they can get both the encrypted data stored in MySQL and the key.

Any ideas? I am thinking I need to move the key to a separate server, and read it in remotely. Or, what about generating the encryption key dynamically for each piece of data. For example taking the customer_id and running md5 on it, and then using that as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Put the secret key in a file, change the file owner to the same user as the web server. Remove all permissions on the file for the group and everyone else.

There's a similar question on Superuser (https://superuser.com/questions/139393/linux-file-permissions-access-control-query) -- I'm sure you could get better help over there, or just by Googling for more information about file permissions on the system you're running.

Comment: Could you tell us what the specific file permissions would be?

Answer (score 0):

A couple options:

1. Save the decryption key to a file with proper permissions
2. If you really want to store the key offsite, "mount" a drive from a different machine. You'd still need to setup permissions properly though.

Bottom line is the master password has to be accessible to the server - which means there's no way to completely wall it off. The best you can do is set user/group permissions on it and make sure it's outside the web root.

If you don't need the ability to decode the value back to plain text (ie if you are just comparing values like a password) consider using a hash instead.